# SnakeYAML version not changing from 1.30 to 1.33 for my springboot project

Tags: spring-boot, maven, dependencies, pom.xml, snakeyaml

These are the lines in my pom.xml:

```
<snakeyaml.version>1.33</snakeyaml.version>
```

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
    <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
    <version>${snakeyaml.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

I added the new version dependency but the project still uses version 1.30. I believe some other things are controllling cthe snakeyaml version

I excluded all conflicting transitive dependencies and still the problem is not solved.
I am using springboot version: 2.7.6 for the project.

Comment: Only adding the `snakeyaml.version` should be enough. Please add your full `pom.xml` instead of a snippet as those don't expose the issue.

Comment: Sorry cannot add pom.xml as its owned by my company.

Comment: I read somewhere only springboot 3.0 supports snakeyaml 1.33, if that's the case should i update the springboot?

Comment: It should be backwards compatible, if you cannot show the pom we cannot help you. Adding the version should be enough so something else in there is forcing the other version.

Comment: Is the `<dependency>` entry in `<dependencyManagement>`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to exclude the snakeyaml from groupId:org.springframework.boot artifactId:spring-boot-starter and then add your dependency you mentioned above.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).